# Python, how i can get gif frames

Tags: python, frame, gif

I am looking some kind method to get gif frames number. I am looking on Google, StackOverflow and any other sites and I find only rubbish! Someone know how to do it? I need only simple number of gif frames.

Answer (score 23):

Which method are you using to load/manipulate the frame? Are you using PIL? If not, I suggest checking it out: [Python Imaging Library](http://www.pythonware.com/products/pil/) and specifically [the PIL gif page](http://www.pythonware.com/library/pil/handbook/format-gif.htm).

Now, assuming you are using PIL to read in the gif, it's a pretty simple matter to determine which frame you are looking at. *seek* will go to a specific frame and *tell* will return which frame you are looking at.

```
from PIL import Image
im = Image.open("animation.gif")

# To iterate through the entire gif
try:
    while 1:
        im.seek(im.tell()+1)
        # do something to im
except EOFError:
    pass # end of sequence
```

Otherwise, I believe you can only find the number of frames in the gif by seeking until an exception (EOFError) is raised.

Comment: I had to change "import Image" into "from PIL import Image" to make it work (I'm guessing I have a recent Pillow version installed)

Comment: See my [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7503567/python-how-i-can-get-gif-frames/60121528#60121528) below if you need to load an image from a byte array.

Comment: I just want to add that you should be able to get the number of frames using im.n_frames (so the above code could just simply use a "for loop" instead).

Comment: Warning: if two adjacent frames are identical, this method will yield only one frame!

Answer (score 13):

Just parse the file, gifs are pretty simple:

```
class GIFError(Exception): pass

def get_gif_num_frames(filename):
    frames = 0
    with open(filename, 'rb') as f:
        if f.read(6) not in ('GIF87a', 'GIF89a'):
            raise GIFError('not a valid GIF file')
        f.seek(4, 1)
        def skip_color_table(flags):
            if flags & 0x80: f.seek(3 << ((flags & 7) + 1), 1)
        flags = ord(f.read(1))
        f.seek(2, 1)
        skip_color_table(flags)
        while True:
            block = f.read(1)
            if block == ';': break
            if block == '!': f.seek(1, 1)
            elif block == ',':
                frames += 1
                f.seek(8, 1)
                skip_color_table(ord(f.read(1)))
                f.seek(1, 1)
            else: raise GIFError('unknown block type')
            while True:
                l = ord(f.read(1))
                if not l: break
                f.seek(l, 1)
    return frames
```

Comment: I'm assuming this requires PIL, I tried using this on a 44 frame `gif` file, and it returned 0 on me... (I counted the frames using Preview, but I need some code to get me the info on over 2500 images)...

Comment: @Zizouz212: This worked for me with the `small_globe.gif` test file I used in [my answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/28549748/355230) to another question of yours. Please upload your 44 frame gif image file somewhere (like in one of your questions), and then let me know so I can download it and see if I can figure out what's causing the problem.

Comment: In Python 3+ you have to change the strings to byte strings or the comparisons will return `False`. E.g. `'GIF87a'` >> `b'GIF87a'`, `','` >> `b','`, etc.

Answer (score 6):

I was faced with the same problem recently and found the documentation on GIFs particularly lacking.  Here's my solution using [imageio's get_reader](https://imageio.readthedocs.io/en/stable/userapi.html#imageio.get_reader) to read the bytes of an image (useful if you just [fetched the image via HTTP](https://requests.readthedocs.io/en/master/), for example) which conveniently stores frames in [numpy matrices](https://imageio.readthedocs.io/en/stable/userapi.html):

```
import imageio
gif = imageio.get_reader(image_bytes, '.gif')

# Here's the number you're looking for
number_of_frames = len(gif)

for frame in gif:
  # each frame is a numpy matrix
```

If you just need to open a file, use:

```
gif = imageio.get_reader('cat.gif')
```

Answer (score 2):

If you are using PIL ([Python Imaging Library](http://www.pythonware.com/products/pil/)) you can use the [`n_frames`](https://pillow.readthedocs.io/en/stable/reference/plugins.html#PIL.GifImagePlugin.GifImageFile.n_frames) attribute of an image object.

See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51535698/2846406).

Answer (score 1):

Ok, 9 years maybe are a little too much time, but here is my answer

```
import tkinter as tk
from PIL import Image  

    

def number_of_frames(gif):
    "Prints and returns the number of frames of the gif"
    print(gif.n_frames)
    return gif.n_frames


def update(ind):
    global root, label

    frame = frames[ind]
    ind += 1
    if ind == frameCnt:
        ind = 0
    label.configure(image=frame)
    root.after(100, update, ind)


file = Image.open("001.gif")
frameCnt = number_of_frames(file)
root = tk.Tk()
frames = [tk.PhotoImage( file='001.gif', format = f'gif -index {i}')
            for i in range(frameCnt)]
label = tk.Label(root)
label.pack()
root.after(0, update, 0)
root.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 1):

I did some timings on the currently proposed answers, which might be of interest:

- Pillow seek: `13.2 ms ± 58.3 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)`
- Custom parsing: `115 µs ± 647 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10000 loops each)`
- Pillow n_frames: `13.2 ms ± 169 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)`
- ImageIO improps (via pillow): `13.1 ms ± 23.1 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)`

So despite being pure python, custom parsing is about 100x faster than using pillow ... interesting. Among the other solutions, I like the ImageIO one, because it is short; however, I'm one of the devs there so I am obviously biased.

---

Setup code:

```py
# get a test GIF (as in-memory stream to avoid measuring file IO)
import imageio.v3 as iio
import io

gif_array = iio.imread("imageio:newtonscradle.gif", index=None)
test_file = io.BytesIO()
iio.imwrite(test_file, gif_array, format="GIF")

# ImageIO is more strict with file handling and would close test_file
# It does handle byte strings natively though, so we can pass that for timings
gif_bytes = iio.imwrite("<bytes>", gif_array, format="GIF")
```

**Pillow seek**:

```py
%%timeit

from PIL import Image

test_file.seek(0) # reset file

n_frames = 1  # opening returns the first frame
with Image.open(test_file) as file:
    # To iterate through the entire gif
    try:
        while 1:
            file.seek(file.tell()+1)
            n_frames += 1
            # do something to im
    except EOFError:
        pass # end of sequence

assert n_frames == 36
```

**Custom Parsing**

```py
%%timeit

class GIFError(Exception): pass

def get_gif_num_frames(filename):
    frames = 0
    with io.BytesIO(filename) as f:  # I modified this line to side-step measuring IO
        if f.read(6) not in (b'GIF87a', b'GIF89a'): # I added b to mark these as byte strings
            raise GIFError('not a valid GIF file')
        f.seek(4, 1)
        def skip_color_table(flags):
            if flags & 0x80: f.seek(3 << ((flags & 7) + 1), 1)
        flags = ord(f.read(1))
        f.seek(2, 1)
        skip_color_table(flags)
        while True:
            block = f.read(1)
            if block == b';': break  # I also added a b'' here
            if block == b'!': f.seek(1, 1) # I also added a b'' here 
            elif block == b',':  # I also added a b'' here
                frames += 1
                f.seek(8, 1)
                skip_color_table(ord(f.read(1)))
                f.seek(1, 1)
            else: raise GIFError('unknown block type')
            while True:
                l = ord(f.read(1))
                if not l: break
                f.seek(l, 1)
    return frames

n_frames = get_gif_num_frames(gif_bytes)
assert n_frames == 36
```

**Pillow n_frames:**

```py
%%timeit

from PIL import Image

test_file.seek(0) # reset file

with Image.open(test_file) as file:
    # To iterate through the entire gif
    n_frames = file.n_frames

assert n_frames == 36
```

**ImageIO's improps (via pillow):**

```py
%%timeit

import imageio.v3 as iio

props = iio.improps(gif_bytes, index=None)
n_frames = props.shape[0]
assert n_frames == 36
```

---

There is also a new PyAV based plugin I'm writing which is faster than pillow, but still slower than the pure-python approach. Syntax-wise it's pretty similar to the *ImageIO (via pillow)* approach:

```py
%%timeit
# IIO improps (via PyAV)
# 507 µs ± 17.7 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000 loops each)
# Note: at the time of this writing this approach is still a PR.
#       it needs documentation and test coverage before being merged.

import imageio.v3 as iio

props = iio.improps(gif_bytes, index=None, plugin="pyav")
n_frames = props.shape[0]
assert n_frames == 36
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's some code that will get you a list with the duration value for each frame in the GIF:

```
from PIL import Image
gif_image = Image.open("animation.gif")
metadata = []

for i in range(gif_image.n_frames):
    gif_image.seek(i)
    duration = gif_image.info.get("duration", 0)
    metadata.append(duration)
```

You can modify the above code to also capture other data from each frame such as background color index, transparency, or version. The `info` dictionary on each frame looks like this:

```
{'version': b'GIF89a', 'background': 0, 'transparency': 100, 'duration': 70}
```