# is there a simple portable way to read a gif image using python (no PIL)?

Tags: python, gif

I am using python inside another application (CINEMA 4D) create a nice connection to out issue tracker (Jira) inside the application. Rationale behind this is to make it really easy for our plugin users to report and track bugs and have things like machine specs, screenshots or attaching scene files (including textures) automatically.

So far it as been a really smooth ride and the integration is coming along great. I started grabbing the icons for issue priorities, projects, issue types, etc. from Jira as well so they can be displayed for better overview. To read the image files I am using CINEMA 4D functionality that is available inside its python binding.

The problem now is, that most icons from Jira come in GIF format and the CINEMA 4D SDK doesn't read GIF files directly (actually it does read them, but only through a back door so users can load them, but I can't use that functionality through Python or the SDK). So I need another way to read the GIF files.

There are a few questions on stackoverflow that go into this direction, but they all seem to recommend PIL. This doesn't feel like the right solution for a few reasons:

1. While that looks nice, it's not part of the standard distribution and seems to be really only maintained for Windows (even though there *are* builds for Mac OS X).
2. It also seems to install itself into the current system installation of Python, but CINEMA 4D comes with its own, so I'd have to rip it apart and distribute it with my plugin.
3. And then it is quite large, while I really only want a compact script to have a compact solution (preferably out of the box, but that doesn't seem to be an option)

I was wondering if there is a simpler or at least more compact way. Since GIF seems to be a relatively simple file format, I am wondering if there may even be a simple parser as a python function/class.

I found a link where somebody disassembles a gif files embedded frames, but doesn't actually grab the image contents: [Python, how i can get gif frames](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7503567/python-how-i-can-get-gif-frames)

I'm fine with putting in some time on my own, and I would've already been coding away if the file format was something uncompressed, but I am a little reluctant since the compression seems to raise the bar slightly.

Comment: Did you take a look at Pillow, a PIL fork that may address some of your concerns?

Comment: Can you read the gif in binary mode `open('image.gif','rb')` and work with that?

Comment: I wouldn't consider GIF simple because it uses LZW compression for the bitmap data. You'll probably want a library to decode it, and PIL is the go-to for this problem. You can find an LZW decompressor in other languages but in pure Python it's likely to be too slow.

Comment: @BioGeek Opening the gif in binary and working with that is exactly what the stackoverflow link I added started doing. The problem is more along the way of what Mark is saying. LZW compression, while known for a while, is not exactly trivial. Performance is not so much my personal concern for the above, since it's mostly 16x16px images, but for somebody actually taking the time doing this, it certainly is...

Comment: if everyone points to PIL/Pillow because it works but you can't use the library directly you could at least take a look at how [pillow handles gif files](https://github.com/python-pillow/Pillow/blob/master/PIL/GifImagePlugin.py), get an idea of what a working algorithm actually takes?