# Python import image gif

Tags: python, image

Good morning, everyone,
I tried to import image logo.gif but got an error message saying the image does not exit.
Appreciate your help.
Dennis

```
from PIL import Image, ImageChops
from PIL.GifImagePlugin import getheader, getdata
img = Image.open("logo.gif")
img.show()

from tkinter import *
window = Tk()

imgLbl = Label( window, image = img )


TclError: image "<PIL.GifImagePlugin.GifImageFile image mode=P size=92x95 at 0x8C92B38>" doesn't exist
```

Answer (score 0):

Please refer to this post [Play Animations in GIF with Tkinter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28518072/play-animations-in-gif-with-tkinter)

This question seems to be a duplicate.
You'll have to first convert the image to tK compatible image by the function PhotoImage present in ImageTk class.