# How to Convert WebP image to Gif with Python?

Tags: python, python-imaging-library, gif, webp

I already tried this:

```
from PIL import Image
im = Image.open('this.webp')
im.save('that.gif', 'gif', save_all=True)
```

which is giving me this error

> TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for &: 'tuple' and 'int'

I have hundreds of webp images on my site and need to convert them to gif, because Firefox doesn't support it.
Thank you.

Comment: Which version of pillow are you using:  I would suggest you to see this issue: https://github.com/python-pillow/Pillow/issues/2949

Comment: I downgraded pillow from 5 to 4.3.0. It fixed the issue. Now the problem is the animations are gone.

Comment: take a look at this @AzimjonPulatov https://stackoverflow.com/a/28519037/3712531

Comment: Please provide a WEP file that doesn't work for us to test with.

Answer (score 8):

Set background to None before saving.

```
from PIL import Image
im = Image.open('this.webp')
im.info.pop('background', None)
im.save('that.gif', 'gif', save_all=True)
```

Thanks to: https://github.com/python-pillow/Pillow/issues/2949#issuecomment-419422861

Comment: is it possible to increase the quality of the resulted gif ?

Comment: @FeraruSilviuMarian Yes probably. You should check the documentation of the pillow package.

Comment: Been doing it for hours to no avail

Comment: the saved file is using less colors it seems

Comment: @FeraruSilviuMarian i don't remember the process right now but it may be because of the default options.

Comment: @muratgozel Thanks! Also take into account the possibility of a better transformation quality by setting these extra options: `im.save(str(sys.argv[1]).replace('webp','gif'), 'gif', save_all=True, lossless=True, quality=100, method=6)`. Documentation [here](https://pillow.readthedocs.io/en/latest/handbook/image-file-formats.html#webp)