# How to display an online .webp file in Tkinter using PIL

Tags: python, tkinter

I have an animated .webp file which is hosted online and I tried to display it using Tkinter.Here is my code.

```py
import urllib.request
from PIL import Image, ImageTk
root=tkinter.Tk()
u = urllib.request.urlopen("https://..../.....webp")
raw_data = u.read()
u.close()

im = Image.open(BytesIO(raw_data))
image = ImageTk.PhotoImage(im.resize((470,210)))
Label(root,image=image).pack()
root.mainloop()
```

This works without raising any errors but only displays one frame.Why is that so?
Is there any way how I can solve this issue

Comment: Store the frames in a  array and call them with the after method of tkinter

Comment: can you explain briefly.....i am sorry i didn't understand

Comment: [First thing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52016407/how-to-convert-webp-image-to-gif-with-python) and then the [next thing](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43770948).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on @Atlas435's comment I have made a code which can display webp files in tkinter without downloading them.This is the code:

```py
    from io import BytesIO
    from tkinter import *
    import tkinter
    import urllib.request
    from PIL import Image, ImageTk
    root=tkinter.Tk()
    
    ar=0
    import tkinter as tk
    from PIL import Image, ImageTk
    
    
    
    u = urllib.request.urlopen(url)
    raw_data = u.read()
    u.close()
    
    im = Image.open(BytesIO(raw_data))
    
    from itertools import count
    
    class ImageLabel(tk.Label):
        """a label that displays images, and plays them if they are gifs"""
        def load(self, im):
            if isinstance(im, str):
                im = im
            self.loc = 0
            self.frames = []
    
            try:
                for i in count(1):
                    self.frames.append(ImageTk.PhotoImage(im.copy().resize((470,210))))
                    im.seek(i)
            except EOFError:
                pass
    
            try:
                self.delay = im.info['duration']
            except:
                self.delay = 100
    
            if len(self.frames) == 1:
                self.config(image=self.frames[0])
            else:
                self.next_frame()
    
        def unload(self):
            self.config(image="")
            self.frames = None
    
        def next_frame(self):
            if self.frames:
                self.loc += 1
                self.loc %= len(self.frames)
                self.config(image=self.frames[self.loc])
                self.after(self.delay, self.next_frame)
    lbl = ImageLabel(root)
    lbl.pack()
    lbl.load(im)
    root.mainloop()
```