# Animated GIF with Python Turtle

Tags: python, tkinter, turtle-graphics, animated-gif

I've found a way to display an animated GIF using Python tkinter and I'm trying to make it work with Python Turtle Graphics.

I can get the animated gif to display with the following code, but there are issues.

1) For some reason having `.grid(row=0, column=0)` puts the image off-screen.
2) The image has a surrounding border which I don't want to display.

I've tried `.place()` with various arguments, but none those place the image on the screen.

Any suggestions on how to place the image a a specific position without a border please?

```
# main file

import turtle
import tkinter_gif

screen = turtle.Screen()
canvas = screen.getcanvas()
gif_window = tkinter_gif.ImageLabel(canvas)
gif_window.grid(row=1, column=0)
gif_window.load("giphy.gif")
turtle.done()
```

```
# tkinter_gif.py

import tkinter as tk
from PIL import Image, ImageTk
from itertools import count

class ImageLabel(tk.Label):
    """a label that displays images, and plays them if they are gifs"""
    def load(self, im):
        if isinstance(im, str):
            im = Image.open(im)
        self.loc = 0
        self.frames = []

        try:
            for i in count(1):
                self.frames.append(ImageTk.PhotoImage(im.copy()))
                im.seek(i)
        except EOFError:
            pass

        try:
            self.delay = im.info['duration']
        except:
            self.delay = 100

        if len(self.frames) == 1:
            self.config(image=self.frames[0])
        else:
            self.next_frame()

    def unload(self):
        self.config(image=None)
        self.frames = None

    def next_frame(self):
        if self.frames:
            self.loc += 1
            self.loc %= len(self.frames)
            self.config(image=self.frames[self.loc])
            self.after(self.delay, self.next_frame)
```

Comment: Related [play-animations-in-gif-with-tkinter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28518072)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest to change `ImageLabel` from `tk.Label` to image item of `Canvas` as below:

```
class ImageLabel:
    def __init__(self, canvas):
        self.canvas = canvas

    def load(self, im, x=0, y=0):
        # create a canvas image item
        self.image = self.canvas.create_image(x, y, image=None)
        self.canvas.tag_lower(self.image)

        if isinstance(im, str):
            im = Image.open(im)

        self.frames = []
        try:
            for i in count(1):
                self.frames.append(ImageTk.PhotoImage(im.copy()))
                im.seek(i)
        except EOFError:
            pass

        try:
            self.delay = im.info['duration']
        except:
            self.delay = 100

        num_frames = len(self.frames)
        if num_frames == 1:
            self.canvas.itemconfig(self.image, image=self.frames[0])
        else:
            self.next_frame(0, num_frames)

    def unload(self):
        self.canvas.delete(self.image)
        self.frames = None

    def next_frame(self, loc, total):
        if self.frames:
            self.canvas.itemconfig(self.image, image=self.frames[loc])
            loc = (loc + 1) % total
            self.canvas.after(self.delay, self.next_frame, loc, total)
```

Then load it at specific position:

```
gif_window = tkinter_gif.ImageLabel(canvas)
gif_window.load("giphy.gif", -200, -200) # 0, 0 is the center of canvas
```

Comment: ***`, -200, -200`***: Why don't you use `canvas.create_image(..., anchor='nw', ...`?

Comment: It is just an example and it is up to OP to adjust the parameters/options.

Comment: ***It is just an example***: As always, but **why**?