# Tkinter animation

Tags: python, tkinter

```
num = 0
def animate():
    global num
    print(num)
    img = PhotoImage(file = "gif.gif", format = "gif -index {}".format(100))
    label.configure(image = img)
    num = (num+1)%180
    screen.after(25, animate)
animate()
```

Why the Label... "label" is not updated as the current frame, instead just appears as a default label(gray color)?

Comment: No, I did save the photo in a variable and it still does not work for me

Comment: Saving the photo to a local variable does not work.  Either save it to a global variable or an attribute of the label.

Answer (score 1):

Try saving the image as a global variable, like so

```py
num = 0
img = None
def animate():
    global num
    global img
    print(num)
    img = PhotoImage(file = "gif.gif", format = "gif -index {}".format(num))
    label.configure(image = img)
    num = (num+1)%180
    screen.after(25, animate)
animate()
```

Comment: Excellent! However I realized the program gets slower as far as the frame is higher on index, Do you know why is it so?

Comment: Cant tell you sorry. You can try to load all the frames before starting the animation instead, maybe that'll improve the speed. See an example here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28518072/play-animations-in-gif-with-tkinter

Comment: I tried loading every frame into a single list, but this proccess was way to long - about 9 seconds - just to finish loading every single frame to the list. thanks for your help anyways

Answer (score 0):

Better use `Pillow` module to handle the GIF frames:

```py
from PIL import Image, ImageTk

...

image = Image.open("gif.gif") # load the image

def animate(num=0):
    num %= image.n_frames
    image.seek(num) # seek to the required frame
    img = ImageTk.PhotoImage(image)
    label.config(image=img)
    label.image = img # save a reference of the image
    label.after(25, animate, num+1)

animate()
```

Comment: The colors are all messed up

Comment: It works for me.  Maybe you provide the GIF image for testing.