# Tkinter failing to animate gif

Tags: python, python-3.x, user-interface, tkinter, graphics

I'm using tkinter to animate a gif using guidance from the following pages: 
[Tkinter animation will not work](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28531415/tkinter-animation-will-not-work)

However I cannot get the suggestions to work. Right now I have something like this

```
import tkinter as tk
root = tk.Tk()
frames = [tk.PhotoImage(file = '/home/quantik/Pictures/dice.gif',format="gif -index %i" %(i)) for i in range(5)]
def animate(n):
    if (n < len(frames)):
        label.configure(image=frames[n])
        n+=1
        root.after(300, animate(n))

label = tk.Label(root)
label.pack()
root.after(0, animate(0))
root.mainloop()
```

However it just displays the last image in `frames` I've tried several methods but I keep getting the same result. Does anyone have any suggestions as to why this may be happening?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This code:

```
root.after(300, animate(n))
```

is exactly the same as this code:

```
result = animate(n)
root.after(300, result)
```

Notice what is happening? You don't want to call the function, you want to tell `after` to call it later. You do that like this:

```
root.after(300, animate, n)
```

That tells `root.after` to call the `animate` function after `300` milliseconds, and to pass the value of `n` as an argument to the function.

Comment: This works! I guess I didn't fully understand the `after` documentation I thought it would wait for the `300` milliseconds then call `animate(args)`. Thanks!