# Automatic shape movement over time with tkinter

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

When I run my current program, the triangle shape on this program is only moving once when I press the button. I want my triangle shape to be moving automatically one pixel per unit time, but I am not sure how to make this work.

So far, while doing this program, I still cannot figure out which bits of classes and definitions go where and what to do with such classes and definitions to make them work like what I intended to, as written above.

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import PhotoImage
from tkinter import *
import time

counter = 0
running = False   

class triangle():
    def trianglemovedefine(move_x, move_y):
        canvas.move (triangle3, move_x, move_y)

    def trianglemove():
        triangle.trianglemovedefine(1, 0)

def moveitboi(justmoveit):
    def count(): 
        if running: 
            global counter 
            justmoveit = lambda:triangle.trianglemove()
            #My "per unit time" adjusted to per 1000 microseconds
            justmoveit.after(1000, count)  
            counter += 1
    count()

def Start(justmoveit):
    global running
    running=True
    moveitboi(justmoveit)

root = tk.Tk()
root.geometry("960x600")

label_toptitle = tk.Label(root, text="Program Name", font=(None, 40),)
label_toptitle.grid(row=0, columnspan=3)

label_desc = tk.Label(root, image=pixel, compound="center", width=900, font=(None, 14),
                                          padx=20, pady=10, text=description)

label_desc.grid(row=1, columnspan=3)

canvas = tk.Canvas(width=960, height=300, bg='white')
canvas.grid(row=2, column=0, columnspan=3)

for linecounter in range(49):
        newtextbit = linecounter + 1
        if (newtextbit + 3) % 4 == 0 and newtextbit != 49:
                canvas.create_text((linecounter * 16 + 80), 90,
                                           fill="darkblue",
                                           font="Times 10 bold",
                                           text=newtextbit)
        if (newtextbit + 3) % 4 == 0:
                canvas.create_line(((linecounter * 16 + 80)), 40, ((linecounter * 16 + 80)), 70,
                                           width=1,
                                           fill="black"
                                           )
        else:
                canvas.create_line(((linecounter * 16 + 80)), 50, ((linecounter * 16 + 80)), 70,
                                           width=1,
                                           fill="black"
                                           )
canvas.create_line(73, 70, 860, 70,
                                   width=2,
                                   fill="black"
                                   )
#The Triangle
triangle3 = canvas.create_polygon(75, 25, 86, 25, 80, 40, fill ='red')

f1 = tk.Frame(root, width=70, height=30)
f1.grid(row=3, column=0, sticky='W')

button_record = tk.Button(f1,
                          text="Record",
                          compound="top",
                          command=lambda:triangle.trianglemove(),
                          )

button_record.pack(side='left', padx=140)


root.mainloop()
```

Comment: This sort of thing is usual done by using the universal widget method [`after()`](http://infohost.nmt.edu/tcc/help/pubs/tkinter/web/universal.html) which allows the "scheduling" of updates to the display to occur after a  specified delay. There are many `tkinter` answers here that show how to do this, so I suggest you do a little more research. Answer to questions about how to making clocks or doing animation are often good candidates.

Comment: I do have the `after()` widget, but my problem is how to get my `after()` widget to work as I intended. So far, pressing the button only pushes the triangle once manually. I tried waiting for program to move triangle again by one second, but I didn't see anything moving.

Comment: @martineau I tried looking for some of those types of questions, but I couldn't find any. Any recommended URL links I should look at?

Comment: Your `moveitboi()` function only calls `after()` once. In needs to call it over-and-over to keep things going. Give me a minute and I'll try to find a good one for you...

Comment: Okay, but I currently do not know how to make a function call the `after()` widget over and over. I request some code solution.

Comment: Here's one for the question [Tkinter animation will not work](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28549748/355230). The basic idea is you call `after()` again in the function that it just called. In the linked answer `update_label_image()` which is called *by* `after()` itself calls `after()` to schedule a subsequent call to itself.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After making fairly extensive changes to the code in your question, eventually I was able to get something runnable enough to illustrate how to implement the suggestion I posted in comments about how to do what you want with the universal [`after()`](http://infohost.nmt.edu/tcc/help/pubs/tkinter/web/universal.html) widget method.

**Note how the last line of `moveitboi()` calls `after()` to schedule another call to itself after the specified delay.**

While making the changes I also attempted to make the code mostly follow the [PEP 8 - Style Guide for Python Code](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/) suggestions. I strongly suggest you read it and do the same when writing your own code in the future.

```
import tkinter as tk

class Triangle:
    def __init__(self, canvas, *points, fill=''):
        self.canvas = canvas
        self.obj_id = canvas.create_polygon(*points, fill=fill)

    def move(self, move_x, move_y):
        self.canvas.move(self.obj_id, move_x, move_y)

    def move_right(self):
        self.move(1, 0)


def moveitboi(parent, marker):
    global counter

    if running:
        marker.move_right()
        counter += 1

    # Call this func again after delay.
    parent.after(1000, moveitboi, parent, marker)

def start(parent, marker):
    global running

    if not running:
        running = True
        moveitboi(parent, marker)  # Start triangle position updates.


root = tk.Tk()
root.geometry("960x600")

counter = 0
running = False

label_toptitle = tk.Label(root, text="Program Name", font=(None, 40),)
label_toptitle.grid(row=0, columnspan=3)

# Left out because I don't have the "pixel" image.
#label_desc = tk.Label(root, image=pixel, compound=tk.CENTER, width=900, font=(None, 14),
#                      padx=20, pady=10, text=description)

canvas = tk.Canvas(root, width=960, height=300, bg='white')
canvas.grid(row=2, column=0, columnspan=3)

for linecounter in range(49):
    newtextbit = linecounter + 1
    xposn = linecounter*16 + 80

    if (newtextbit + 3) % 4 == 0 and newtextbit != 49:
        canvas.create_text(xposn, 90, fill="darkblue", font="Times 10 bold",
                           text=newtextbit)
    if (newtextbit + 3) % 4 == 0:
        canvas.create_line(xposn, 40, xposn, 70, width=1, fill="black")
    else:
        canvas.create_line(xposn, 50, xposn, 70, width=1, fill="black")  

canvas.create_line(73, 70, 860, 70, width=2, fill="black")

# Global triangle.
triangle3 = Triangle(canvas, 75, 25, 86, 25, 80, 40, fill='red')

f1 = tk.Frame(root, width=70, height=30)
f1.grid(row=3, column=0, sticky='W')

button_record = tk.Button(f1, text="Record", compound="top",
                          command=lambda: start(root, triangle3))
button_record.pack(side='left', padx=140)

root.mainloop()
```

Here's a screenshot showing the moved position of the red marker several seconds after the <kbd>Record</kbd> button was clicked:

[image: screenshot after clicking Record button]

Comment: Thanks for the link to the PEP 8 Style Guide. I presume PEP 8 Style Guide is a set of guidelines for writing efficient Python code, isn't it?

Comment: Ron: Glad to hear you found my answer useful. PEP 8 is not so much about efficiency as it is about writing readable code—which makes it easier to maintain and for others (including yourself later on) to understand what it's doing.

Comment: P.S. I don't strictly follow PEP 8, just mostly. Use your own judgement—it just guidelines (from some very smart people) and it even says something along those lines near the [beginning](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#a-foolish-consistency-is-the-hobgoblin-of-little-minds).