# In Python, how would I get a gif's keyframes to make a spritesheet

Tags: python, image, animated-gif, sprite-sheet

For a small script I'm writing, part of it requires the ability to split a gif (that would be selected by the user) into it's frames; and then those frames be stitched together on a spritesheet (vertically or horizontally, depending on user choice), and then save that new image with the same name but appending `-sprite`. What's the best library / process to use if ease of distribution is key?

Comment: This may have the answer you're looking for, but it is a couple years old, so there may be something better now: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7503567/python-how-i-can-get-gif-frames

Comment: @mrcheshire that does not give me my answer. That lets you know *how many* frames are in a gif. I need to extrapolate said frames, and stitch them together into a new image. Combining that with the fact that I can't really use PIL, since that's both quite old and isn't for python 3.X

Comment: See [Pillow](https://python-pillow.github.io/).