# Extract key frames from GIF using Python

Tags: python, gif, python-imaging-library, animated-gif

I want to compress a GIF image by extracting 15 frames from the GIF that preferably should be distinct.

I'm using Python and Pillow library and I didn't find any way to get the number of frames a GIF has in the [Pillow docs](https://pillow.readthedocs.io/en/latest/reference/plugins.html#module-PIL.GbrImagePlugin). Neither did I find how to extract a specific frame from a GIF, because [Pillow restricts that](https://pillow.readthedocs.io/en/latest/reference/plugins.html#PIL.GifImagePlugin.GifImageFile.seek).

Is there any way to extract frames without iterating through each frame consequently?
Is there a more advanced Python library for GIF processing?

Comment: @Bram  I'm not sure that the other question is relevant here exactly. This question is about how to jump to an arbitrary frame.

Answer (score 12):

Here is an extension of @radarhere's answer that divides the .gif into `num_key_frames` different parts and saves each part to a new image.

```
from PIL import Image

num_key_frames = 8

with Image.open('somegif.gif') as im:
    for i in range(num_key_frames):
        im.seek(im.n_frames // num_key_frames * i)
        im.save('{}.png'.format(i))
```

The result is `somegif.gif` broken into 8 pieces saved as `0`..`7.png`.

Comment: The 8 frames are probably numbered 0..7 ;-)

Comment: @MarkSetchell, yeah :--) they definitely are.

Comment: So the value added  to the original post is how to use a for loop?

Comment: @mins The value is since the question asked for "extracting 15 frames", and the answer I'm extending almost reaches that goal, my answer takes it all the way.

Comment: The OP didn't know how to perform a random access to a specific frame, he had to restart from frame 0 for any frame. The answer was given by @radarhere: Use `PIL.Image.seek(i)`.

Comment: @mins I believe it is perfectly acceptable to extend an answer on SO to bring the answer further towards what the question is looking for. It may not be the most important detail to iterate over the frames but it is a goal stated in the question. A handful of users have obviously found this answer useful, so what exactly is your point?

Answer (score 9):

For the number of frames, you are looking for n_frames. Take a look at  [here](https://pillow.readthedocs.io/en/stable/reference/plugins.html#PIL.GifImagePlugin.GifImageFile.n_frames).

```
from PIL import Image
im = Image.open('test.gif')
print("Number of frames: "+str(im.n_frames))
```

For extracting a single frame -

```
im.seek(20)
im.save('frame20.jpg')
```

Comment: Link doesn't work

Comment: @Scott - https://pillow.readthedocs.io/en/stable/reference/plugins.html#PIL.GifImagePlugin.GifImageFile.n_frames

Answer (score 0):

The real working solution to extract proper frames of any GIF file:

[BigglesZX/gifextract.py](https://gist.github.com/BigglesZX/4016539)

Answer (score 0):

If you have tf imported you can:

```
def load_gif(file_path):
    with tf.io.gfile.GFile(file_path, 'rb') as f:
        video = tf.io.decode_gif(f.read())
    return np.array(video)
```